# Using python, move files with specific text to a new directory

Tags: python

Fairly new to programming. Trying to make life easier for me here. I have a folder with several thousand simple txt files. Within the files, I am looking for certain key words so I can sort those files to three different folders.

For example, one group of files will have the text "Example Text" printed twice somewhere in the document (not together or in sequence, just randomly). Another group will have the text "Example Text" printed just once somewhere in the document. And another group will not have the phrase "Example Text" anywhere in the document.

I have tried multiple approaches and nothing is quite working correctly. It seems like it should be fairly easy. Can anyone help out? Thanks.

Comment: _I have tried multiple approaches_ Show us.

Comment: You said you've `"tried multiple approaches"`...what were they? Can't help if we don't know what you've tried/

Answer (score 0):

The heart of such a program would probably look like this:

```
def count_phrase_occurrences(filename, phrase):
    '''
    Return the number of times that a phrase appears in a file.
    '''

    occurrences = 0

    with open(filename, 'r') as fp:
        for line in fp:
            if phrase in line:
                occurrences += 1

    return occcurrences
```